# Read local JSON files when dynamically creating functional tests in Intern

Tags: json, dojo, intern

I am creating functional tests dynamically using Intern v4 and dojo 1.7. To accomplish this I am assigning registerSuite to a variable and attaching each test to the Tests property in registerSuite:

```
var registerSuite = intern.getInterface('object').registerSuite;
var assert = intern.getPlugin('chai').assert;

// ...........a bunch more code .........

registerSuite.tests['test_name'] = function() {

    // READ JSON FILE HERE
    var JSON = 'filename.json';

    // ....... a bunch more code ........
}
```

That part is working great. The challenge I am having is that I need to read information from a different JSON file for each test I am dynamically creating. I cannot seem to find a way to read a JSON file while the dojo javascript is running (I want to call it in the `registerSuite.tests` function where it says `// READ JSON FILE HERE`). I have tried dojo's `xhr.get`, node's `fs`, intern's `this.remote.get`, nothing seems to work.

I can get a static JSON file with `define(['dojo/text!./generated_tests.json'])` but this does not help me because there are an unknown number of JSON files with unknown filenames, so I don't have the information I would need to call them in the declare block.

Please let me know if my description is unclear. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating functional tests, they'll always run in Node, so you have access to the Node environment. That means you could do something like:

```
var registerSuite = intern.getPlugin('interface.object').registerSuite;
var assert = intern.getPlugin('chai').assert;

var tests = {};
tests['test_name'] = function () {
    var JSON = require('filename.json');
    // or require.nodeRequire('filename.json')
    // or JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('filename.json', {
    //      encoding: 'utf8'
    //    }))
}

registerSuite('my suite', tests);
```

Another thing to keep in mind is assigning values to `registerSuite.tests` won't (or shouldn't) actually do anything. You'll need to call `registerSuite`, passing it your suite name and tests object, to actually register tests.

Comment: Thanks @jason0x43! The reference to FS was the solution that seemed to work best for me. I had to import the reference to node FS with `define([ 'dojo/json', 'dojo/node!fs'], function(JSON, fs))` and then I was able to call `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(eachTest, 'utf8'));` and load in the file. Everything worked great from there.